# Access JSON data from SE API using Python urllib

Tags: python, json, api, post, urllib

I am trying to retrieve Stack Exchange data for research purposes.

I am using this url to submit a query: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/29407/mentioned?site=stackoverflow. (The id # after "users/" is randomly chosen, but a real id.)

When I enter the url into my browser, I see the JSON data that I want to use in my code. When I encode and submit my request using urllib, I get an error. Where am I going wrong? Here is the code I am using:

```
url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/29407/mentioned'
query = {'site': 'stackoverflow'}
formatted_query = urllib.urlencode(query)
request = urllib2.Request(url,query_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

error:

```
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I'm following closely what I've seen in some online tutorials, but I'm fairly new to this stuff, so I apologize if I'm missing something big.

Comment: what do you get if you add `print query_url` just before the request?

Comment: where is your `formatted_query`? you have to make the full url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `urllib2.Request()` is POST data, not GET query arguments. You need to add your query arguments (and `?`) directly to the end of the url, not pass them in like that because you're making it a POST request.

Comment: i'm not sure i'm grasping this. the tutorials i've seen, including the one [in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html), use a procedure like the one above to generate a POST request. that documentation says that a GET request is only made if *no* second argument is passed to Request.

are you suggesting that i simply use `response = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/29407/mentioned?site=stackoverflow')`? i've tried that, and it doesn't work.

Comment: The request needs to be GET as that's what the API takes, so yes, using the URL with query is correct. You might run into a problem with the output being gzip encoded but that's a separate issue. Consider using the `requests` library, otherwise you need to un-gzip it.

Comment: i think you're right, jason s, the json output was gzipped. i had abandoned that track (putting query directly in url) before when i got weird unicode trying to read the response. i used the `requests` library, which automatically gunzips, as you suggested, and i was able to access the JSON. thank you!